# A case-insensitive list

Tags: c#, .net, string, dictionary, collections

I need a case insensitive list or set type of collection (of strings). What is the easiest way to create one? You can specify the type of comparison you want to get on the keys of a Dictionary, but I can't find anything similar for a List.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like its possible to leverage the KeyedCollection class:

```
public class Set<T> : KeyedCollection<T,T>
{
    public Set()
    {}

    public Set(IEqualityComparer<T> comparer) : base(comparer)
    {}

    public Set(IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        foreach (T elem in collection)
        {
            Add(elem);
        }
    }

    protected override T GetKeyForItem(T item)
    {
        return item;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 33):

Assuming you're using .NET 3.5, you can just use:

```
var strings = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

... or something similar, where you'd pick the appropriate culture setting as well.

A list doesn't really have the idea of a comparison for the most part - only when you call `IndexOf` and related methods. I don't believe there's any way of specifying the comparison to use for that. You could use `List<T>.Find` with a predicate, however.

Comment: I am stuck with .Net 2 sadly :(

Answer (score 23):

Use Linq, this adds a new method to .Compare

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

List<string> MyList = new List<string>();

MyList.Add(...)

if (MyList.Contains(TestString, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) {
    //found
}
```

Comment: You don't need 'Linq' to use the Contains method

Comment: @geo1701: but you **do need** `using System.Linq` to get the new overload with the `StringComparer` !

Comment: Thanks, good answer, I was hoping there was an extension, rather than having to write my own. Otherwise I would not have known where to look!

Comment: However, that does not help one actually get to the item in the list....

Answer (score 2):

Similar story here where looking to check for [contains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring)

e.g.

```
public static bool Contains(this string source, string toCheck, StringComparison comp)
        {
            return source.IndexOf(toCheck, comp) >= 0;
        }
```