# Case invariant search for a string in an array/list of strings

Tags: c#, linq

The following code could be used to search in an array / List of strings using LINQ.

```
String[] someArray
    = { "Test1", "test2", "test3", "TEST4" };

string toCheck = "Test1";

if (someArray.Any(toCheck.Contains))
{
    // found -> Do sth.
}
// or with list 

List<string> someList
    = new List<string>(new string[] { "TEST1", "test2", "test3", "TEST4"  });

if (someList.Any(toCheck.Contains))
{
    // "Test1" != "TEST1"
}
```

But how could you do this case invariant?

My approach was to convert the complete list to upper, and then test using contains:

```
if ((someList.ConvertAll(item => item.ToUpper()).Any(toCheck.ToUpper().Contains)))
{
    // found -> Do sth.
}
```

In this case the original list is not altered.

```
if ((someList.Select(item => item.ToUpper()).Any(toCheck.ToUpper().Contains)))
{
    // works with both
}
```

Well it works... (also with some language specific things like the turkish 'i' letter... (also we still don't have turkish customers as far as i know.. but who knows if they're are in  future?)), but it seems not very elegant.

Is there a way to do an case invariant comparision if an item is in a list?

Best regards,
Offler

Comment: possible duplicate of [A case-insensitive list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530748/a-case-insensitive-list)

Comment: Case insensitive contains: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring?rq=1

Comment: Are you confusing invariant with insensitive?

Comment: Your examples don't need to use `Contains`. Should `"TeSt1"` match `"tEsT12"`?

Comment: @ric this is a another topic. it is not if a string contains a substirng like your link.

Comment: @AlexFilipovici The list itself should not be altered. It is only about a method to find a stirng in a list or array or ...

Comment: @jodrell Contains is only needed as the result should be true in case of substrings. Ans yes in this case it should match, good comment, forgotten to put it in the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `Contains` use [`IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425.aspx) with [`StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison.aspx):

```
String[] strings = { "Test1", "test2", "test3", "TEST4" };
String text = "TEST123";
if (strings.Any(str => text.IndexOf(str, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1))
{
    // we will enter this if clause
}
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/obYeLf)

Comment: But won't that also match for substrings?

Comment: @BobVale: Yes, that's what OP wants, the same what `Contains` does. Actually `String.Contains` uses `IndexOf` internally. I've edited my answer to clarify what it does and to add a demo.

Comment: Doh, completely missed that, misread that as collection contains search string.

Comment: @BobVale yes, missed to put it in the question, was to focussed on a specific solution. If an exact match would be needed Tims solution could be changed to `Equals` instead of `IndexOf`, but `IndexOf` is the right one for my purpose

Answer (score 1):

Could you not just do a simple check with the [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425.aspx) that uses the appropriate [StringComparison](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison.aspx) value?  For example:

```
if(someArray.Any(s => s.IndexOf(toCheck, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) != -1)
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: But that would match if the match was a substring of the other

Comment: @BobVale Since the OP used Contains in his original code, I'm assuming that's his intent.

Comment: Doh, completely missed that, misread that as collection contains search string.